# Tensorflow Depthwise Convolution Understanding

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I'm currently trying to understand how Tensorflow's [Depthwise Convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d) works. As far as I've understood, each channel in the input image is convolved with it's own set of filters, and then the results are concatenated. I'm going to stick with the parameter `depth_multiplier=1` for the sake of simplicity in the remainder, so `n_inputchannels == n_outputchannels`.

So in theory, I could split up the depthwise convolution into `N` individual, regular `Conv2Ds`, correct? Why does the following code produce different results then I am wondering - is this a precision issue? I'm following the documentation for the ordering `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, 1]` for the depthwise convolution filters, and `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]` for the regular convolutions, and `NHWC` data format.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

width = 128
height = 128
channels = 32
kernel_width = 3
kernel_height = 3

with tf.Session() as sess:

    _input = np.float32(np.random.rand(1, height, width, channels))
    _weights =  np.float32(np.random.rand(kernel_height, kernel_width, channels, 1))

    _input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, height, width, channels))
    _weights_pc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(kernel_height, kernel_width, channels, 1))

    feed = { _input_ph: _input, _weights_pc : _weights }

    result = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(_input_ph, _weights_pc, [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')

    individual_results = []
    for i in range(channels):
        individual_results.append(tf.nn.conv2d(tf.expand_dims(_input_ph[:,:,:,i],axis=3), tf.expand_dims(_weights_pc[:,:,i,:],axis=3), [1,1,1,1], 'SAME'))

    depth_result = sess.run(result, feed_dict=feed)
    concat_result = sess.run(tf.concat(individual_results, axis=3), feed_dict=feed)

    channel_diff = 0.0
    for i in range(channels):
        channel_diff += np.sum(depth_result[:,:,:,i]-concat_result[:,:,:,i])

    print(channel_diff)
```

Here I'm computing first the normal `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` and then slice the input and weights accordingly and do `tf.nn.conv2d`s individually. For these parameters I get about `1e-5` difference, but that tends to get higher when I increase the number of channels.

I would be really glad if someone could explain to me what's going on :) 
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a precision issue, try _input = np.float32(np.random.randint(0, 100,1, heigh,twidth, channels)), so that they are large values, but integers. Same for the weights.